# Upgrading a piece of code from jQuery 1.3.2 to the latest version

Tags: javascript, jquery

This code works in jQuery 1.3.2

```
        $(document).ready(function() {

            $(function() {
                $("#proiecte").click(function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $("#ThisWillScroll").removeClass() .addClass("slide1");
                    $("#menu li a").removeClass(), $("#proiecte").addClass("active");
                });
            });

            $(function() {
                $("#desprenoi").click(function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $("#ThisWillScroll").removeClass() .addClass("slide2"),
                    $("#menu li a").removeClass(), $("#desprenoi").addClass("active");
                });
            });

        });
```

However when I replace the library with the latest version (1.6.2), it stops working.

I'm not very well versed in jQuery and have no clue what it could be inside my code that stops it from working. A deprecated function maybe ?

--

It has been solved.

I had a piece of forgotten code which messed up the script.

Thanks to [genesis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/764846/genesis) for pointing out there's a JS console, I had no clue there was something like that (I mainly work in design).

Comment: Yes ! I didn't think of checking that, but turns out I had a forgotten piece of code from a slider. Works without it. :)

Comment: I can't see anything obviously wrong in your code. The error must be somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

both `$(document).ready(function() {` and `$(function() {`
 does same thing..so use of doc.ready will be fine ..try below code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                $("#proiecte").click(function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $("#ThisWillScroll").removeClass() .addClass("slide1");
                    $("#menu li a").removeClass(), $("#proiecte").addClass("active");
                });

                $("#desprenoi").click(function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $("#ThisWillScroll").removeClass() .addClass("slide2"),
                    $("#menu li a").removeClass(), $("#desprenoi").addClass("active");
                });

        });
```

other wise your code looks fine to me.